# $1$-factorizability for linear hypergraphs with infinite edges on $\omega$

Tags: infinite-combinatorics, hypergraph, matching-theory, perfect-matchings

Let $H=(V,E)$ be a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph). We say that $M\subseteq E$ is a *matching* if the members of $M$ are pairwise disjoint, and $M$ is said to be *perfect* if $\bigcup M = E$. Moreover, $H$ is $1$-*factorizable* if $E$ is the disjoint union of perfect matchings.

Let $[\omega]^\omega$ denote the set of infinite subsets of $\omega$. We say that the hypergraph $(\omega, E)$ is *linear* if $\varnothing \neq E\subseteq[\omega]^\omega$ and $E$ has the following property:

> $e_1\neq e_2\in E$ implies $|e_1\cap e_2|\leq 1$.

We say $(\omega, E)$ is *maximal* if for $E_1\subseteq [\omega]^\omega$ with $E\subseteq E_1$ and $E\neq E_1$ we have that $(\omega, E_1)$ is not a linear hypergraph.

Is  there a $1$-factorizable maximal linear hypergraph $H = (V,E)$ with $|E|=\aleph_0$ and $\bigcup E = \omega$?

Comment: What about a countably infinite projective plane? If we regard the points as vertices and the lines as edges, then it's a "maximal linear hypergraph" with $\aleph_0$ vertices and $\aleph_0$ edges, and it doesn't even have two disjoint edges, let alone a perfect matching.

Comment: That's right - thanks @bof for the question and for your remark. By regular I meant $|e| =\aleph_0$ for all $e\in E$. And I should exclude the projective plane (and similar hypergraphs) from the question

Comment: Does anyone else use "regular hypergraph" this way? As far as Iknoe, hypergraphs where all hyperedges have the same size are called "uniform", and "regular" means that all vertices have the same degree.

Comment: A countably infinite **affine** plane, regarded as a hypergraph with points as vertices and lines as edges, is a maximal linear hypergraph with $\aleph_0$ vertices and $\aleph_0$ edges, and it is $1$-factorizable; each maximal family of parallel lines is a perfect matching.

Comment: I think this is analogous the Erdos-Faber-Lovasz conjecture for infinite hypergrphs

Comment: @vidyarthi Thanks for your comment. Erdos-Faber-Lovasz is about coloring, though, and this is about 1-factorizability. But maybe you know a link between colouring and 1-factorizability that I am not aware of? I would be interested in this for sure!

Comment: No, i just thought of extending the fact that any regular graph with degree $d$ is $d$-edge colorable iff it is 1-factorizable to linear hypergraphs. May be we have to specify the degree of each vertex in the hypergraph to have a proper equivalence between factorizability and colorability